# google cloud storage client library

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

How to enable default bucket for GCS library.

I cant below options in my project console.

If your app doesn't have a default bucket, create one:
In the Google Cloud Platform Console, go to the Application settings.
Scroll to the bottom of the page to Cloud Integration.
Click Create and wait for the bucket to be created. The bucket will be completely set up and ready for use.

Note: AM using Free account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable billing in order to use Google Cloud Storage.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/signup?hl=en

> Note: For most projects, Google Cloud Storage is enabled by default. You will still need to enable billing before using Google Cloud Storage.